# How do I get the value of the key if the key in the Map is an array?

Tags: javascript, es6-map

Only the reference to the same object, the Map structure will treat it as the same key. If the `key` in Map is an array, the `get` method cannot read the key and returns undefined.

```
const map = new Map();

map.set(['a'], 111);
map.get(['a']) // undefined
```

How can I get the value `111` of the key `['a']` by `get` method or any other way?

Correct approach for output:

```
const map = new Map(); 

map.set('a', 112);  
console.log(map.get('a')); // 112
```

OR

```
const map = new Map(); 

var a=['a','b','c'];

map.set(a[0], 112);  
console.log(map.get(a[0])); // 112
```

Comment: Define the array beforehand rather than creating two separate arrays

Comment: You solved my problem, thank you!